# How to count repeated cell values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to count the repeated word as one in serial number using Excel?

For example:

Below are subject code

```
BC02551
BC02551
BC02551
BC02552
BC02552
TQ22
TQ123
TQ123
```

Now I want to count the code which are similar as one. Like below:

```
Sr. No.

  1       BC02551
          BC02551
          BC02551
  2       BC02552
          BC02552
  3       TQ22
  4       TQ123
          TQ123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the subject codes are sorted in column B and are continuous without any empty cells in between, with the first entry at cell B2.

In cell A2, enter the formula `=IF(B1=B2,"",MAX(A$1:A1)+1)` and drag the formula down and you can produce the output as in your question.

Alternatively, if you simply want to count how many unique items are there, you can use the "Remove Duplicates" function in Excel and count how many unique items remained.  In Excel 2013, "Remove Duplicates" can be found under ribbon "Data" > "Data Tools".

Comment: :) you just sniped my answer. It's a little neater than mine too, think I'll use it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data you shared was in B2:B9, add the following to C2:

```
=IF(B2=B1,C1,C1+1)
```

Then, add the following to D2:

```
=IF(C2<>C1,C2,"")
```

Drag/fill both formulae down the list. You can hide column C if you don't want to see it, it's just a helper column. Column D will show the counts as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel Pivot Table

> Select a cell in the pivot table, and in the Excel Ribbon, under
>   PivotTable Tools, click the Design tab. Click Report Layout, and
>   select Compact Form or Outline Form. (In Tabular Form, subtotals are
>   only shown at the bottom.) Click Subtotals, and click Show all
>   Subtotals at Top of Group.

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot13.html